# Monitor real time scroll position on mobile safari, iOS 6 and 7

Tags: javascript, ios, css, safari, scroll

I've found many posts about this on SO and the web, but many are old, and I've never found a fully working answer. I'm trying to fix an advertisement on my web page so that when the user scrolls below it, it changes to `position:fixed`, and is therefore always viewable. I've played around with `gesturechange` and `touchmove`, but both only get me half way there.

How, in realtime, can I monitor the position of the window while the user is scrolling on safari in iOS 6 or 7? This includes while the screen is still scrolling after the user has lifted there finger (momentum scrolling)

Comment: I've tried and tried to find a solution to this myself, and I think the unfortunate answer is that... you simply can't.

Comment: Yep, I've came to the same conclusion. It really feels like Apple doesn't care about developers unless they are developing an app =/

Answer (score 0):

A simple way a little bit tricky.

In your css
==>

```
#myAd {
position: relative;
}


#myAd.fixed {
position: fixed;


}
```

In your html
==>

```
<div id="myAd" class="sample fixed">
<!--PUT YOUR AD HERE-->
</div>
```

And some jQuery Stuff
==>

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    if ( $('#myAd').length > 0 ) {
      myAd_top = $('#myAd').position().top;
      $(window).scroll( function(e) {
      if ( window.scrollY > myAd_top ) {
      document.getElementById('myAd').className = 'sample fixed';
      } else {
      document.getElementById('myAd').className = 'sample';
      }
      });
    } 
  });
</script>
```

Comment: the problem is that the scroll event fires AFTER the scrolling has finished, so the AD doesn't become sticky until the scrolling has already stopped